# I want to create a service based on config data

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I am trying to make a service with spring boot framework.

So right now I have a service ready and I want to write a bean for my service. However the way I am doing it is giving me an error that attribute must be a constant. Is there a way to write a bean to generate a service as I want?

The config file looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig {

    static DataSource.Type dst = ...;
    static ItemSource.Type ist = ...;

    @Bean
    public ServiceEngine getServiceEngine (
            @DataSource( dst ) RuleStore < SKURule > rs,
            @ItemSource( ist ) SKUStore ss
    ) {

        return new ServiceEngine( rs, ss );
    }

    @Target({ElementType.FIELD,
            ElementType.METHOD,
            ElementType.TYPE,
            ElementType.PARAMETER})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Qualifier
    public @interface ItemSource {

        Type value();

        enum Type {
            LOCAL,
            API,
        }
    }

    @Target({ElementType.FIELD,
            ElementType.METHOD,
            ElementType.TYPE,
            ElementType.PARAMETER})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Qualifier
    public @interface DataSource {

        Type value();

        enum Type {
            LOCAL,
            S3,
        }
    }
    ...
    // other beans
    ...
}
```

Comment: Error where, exactly?

Comment: "attribute must be a constant" from getServiceEngine